# Copy input values from one form to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the best way to copy input values from one form to another where the inputs in each form have the same name?  I came up with the following, however, it seems terribly inefficient (I know, efficiency probably doesn't matter, but would still like to know).  Thanks

http://jsbin.com/beyixeqa/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $('#copy').click(function(){
                    var form1=$('#form1').find(':input');
                    var form2=$('#form2');
                    form1.each(function() {
                        var $t=$(this);
                        form2.find('[name="'+$t.attr('name')+'"]').val($t.val());
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="copy">copy</button>
        <form id="form1">
            <input name="a" type=text>
            <input name="b" type=text>
            <input name="c" type=text>
            <input name="d" type=text>
        </form>
        <form id="form2">
            <input name="a" type=text>
            <input name="b" type=text>
            <input name="c" type=text>
            <input name="d" type=text>
        </form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is your form so simple?

Comment: @Satpal.  Yes, but more values.

Comment: You may use jquery clone function but it will copy DOM element not just the value

Comment: @Satpal The second form needs to be HTML.  My whole reason to do this is to allow non-JS users to be able to submit both forms, but JS users to only need to submit one form.

Comment: You can try http://jsbin.com/beyixeqa/2/. Here I have used `clone()` and `replaceWith()`

Comment: @PedroEstrada.  Type.  Fixed.  My thought was to somehow iterate over `$('#form2').find(':input')` and update the values instead of a bunch of `finds`.

Comment: @Satpal Interesting approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to clone or replace, just change the `value`

```js
jQuery(function( $ ) {


  function copyForms( $form1 , $form2 ) {
    $(':input[name]', $form2).val(function() {
      return $(':input[name=' + this.name + ']', $form1).val();
    });
  }

  $('#copy').on('click', function() {
    copyForms(  $('#form1') , $('#form2')  );
  });


});
```

```css
/*this demo only*/
body{display:flex;}form{padding:16px;background:#ddd;}form>*{box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;}
```

```html
<form id=form1>
  FORM
  <input    name=a type=text value="FOO">
  <input    name=b type=button value="BAR">
  <textarea name=c>BAZ</textarea>
  <select   name=d>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected>b</option>
  </select>
</form>

<button id="copy">COPY&rarr;</button>

<form id=form2>
  HIDDEN FORM
  <input    name=a type=text>
  <input    name=b type=button value="...">
  <textarea name=c></textarea>
  <select   name=d>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

- By using `:input[name]` you're making sure to target **only** `:input`s with a `name` attribute
- `$(':input[name]', form2)` = descendants of `#form2`
- Using the `val` callback you can target every single one of the targeted inputs
- returning their values to be exactly as their referenced *same-named-* `:inputs` of `#form1`

Comment: Thanks Roko.  I like it!  Do you know if I can only select certain inputs to copy?  Was thinking of putting `class="copyClass"` on some of the inputs in form1, and then something like `':input[name].copyClass'`

Comment: How to make it case insensitive ?

Comment: In example I could have in form1 name="SeaRCH" and in form2="search".

Comment: @InnerWorld you mean like: http://jsbin.com/manune/1/edit?html,js,output ? Have you tried to understand the above code? I mean a simple google for "how to return a value to lowercase" would lead you in seconds to a solution! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**.clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [**.replaceWith()**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('#copy').click(function(){
    var newform2=$('#form1').clone(); //Clone form 1
    newform2.filter('form').prop('id', 'form2'); //Update formID
    $('#form2').replaceWith(newform2);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/beyixeqa/2/edit)