# How do I add forms together in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a form that has multiple sections.  I want to add each of these to a "finalsubmit" form.  How can I add the entire section forms to the final one?

```html
 <form id='1'  name='1' method='POTS' action='#'>
    <input type='text' id='blah' name='blah'>
    <input type='text' id='blahblah' name='blahblah'>
    <input type='button' id='sub1' value='Submit'>
</form>
<form id='2' class='section' name='2' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='text' id='blah2' name='blah2'>
    <input type='text' id='blahblah2' name='blahblah2'>
    <input type='button' id='sub2' value='Submit'>
</form>


<form id='finalForm' name='finalForm' method='POST' action='#'>
</form>
```

jQuery (in laymen's terms)

```js
$('#sub1 #sub2').click(function(){
     //Grab all the data from clicked form and add it to $('#finalForm');
 });
```

Comment: You mean `#sub1, #sub2` to match either ID.

Comment: See if this can answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015925/copy-input-values-from-one-form-to-another

Comment: When you say "and add it to $('#finalForm')", you mean added as hidden input ? or original inputs with their values ?

Comment: just basically copy the entire form from form1 to finalform

Comment: Why bother with multiple `form` elements at all? It's not like they're pointing at different actions or anything. Just use `fieldset` or `section` or the ol' standby `div` to wrap them.

Comment: So you are just copying all the form elements?

Comment: yea, as a final "this is all the data you submitted" check.

Answer (score 1):

Use `appendTo()` to append the form contents to the other form.

```
$("form#1, form#2").children().appendTo("#finalForm");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depents how your final form should look like.
If it exists of the inputs from form 1 and form 2 then I would recommend you the way Barmar already posted, otherwise you prevent the submit of both forms and then you get the values of the input fields.

```html
<form id='firstForm' name='1' method='POST'>
      <input type='text' id='blah' name='blah'>
      <input type='text' id='blahblah' name='blahblah'>
      <input type="submit" id="sub1">
   </form>

   <form id='2' class='section' name='2' method='POST' action='#'>
      <input type='text' id='blah2' name='blah2'>
      <input type='text' id='blahblah2' name='blahblah2'>
      <input type='button' id='sub2' value='Submit'>
   </form>


   <form id='finalForm' name='finalForm' method='POST' action='#'>
   </form>

   <script>

      $("form").submit(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         // Input Fields from first form
         const blah = $('#blah').val();
         const blahblah = $('#blahblah').val();

         // Input Fields from second form
         const blah2 = $('#blah2').val();
         const blahblah2 = $('#blahblah2').val();

         // Insert the data into your final form
         
         // Write the inputs in your static html

         // Or you create new Inputs with jQuery
         var exampleInput = $("<input>");
         exampleInput.innerHTML = "Text.";
         $("#finalForm").append(exampleInput);
      });

   </script>
```